# Is the "P/Q tag" field before the "Length/Type" field in the Ethernet frame header?

Tags: c, networking

I need to handle Ethernet frame directly in C. And I got confused by the order of fields in Ethernet frame header. This is a programming question, so please do not mark it as offtopic.

The following figure is from Page 85 of book "TCP/IP Illustrated Volume 1, 2nd Edition".
[image: IEEE Packet Structure]

As it shows, the "length or type" field precedes the "P/Q Tag" field (if there is any).

However, after hexdumping the frame I received, I realized the frame I received has "length or type" follows "P/Q Tag". See below

```
0100 5e00 007b Destination MAC (multicast)
000f 5325 fb00 Source MAC 
8100           Q-tagged frame. (802.1q standard uses it to denote VLAN).    
0065           Prio (3 bits), CFI (1bit), VLAN ID(12 bit)
0800           EtherType (Type field)
4500           IP packet starts from here.
```

**Question 1:** What is the order of these two fields.
**Question 2:** How can I check the size of Ethernet frame header correctly. Need to know where the IP packet starts.

Comment: This looks like a little-endian versus big-endian issue.

Comment: Isn't there a header file that defines a `struct` for this? It will take care of this for you.

Comment: @Barmar Interesting. Because I just debugged one in decoding the UDP header length field. I think the frame I get is always big-endian. My box is little-endian. My hexdump function reads byte by byte, so there shouldn't be litle-endian issue, right? So, when the NIC writes this frame in my memory, does it write byte by byte?

Comment: @Barmar Nice suggestion. Could you be specific? It would be very helpful to know how the BSD socket handles the frame in low level. Do you know where can I find it? By the way, my use case requires high performance, that's why I am directly adding/substracting pointers in the frame. I don't know whether a `struct` will affect performacne? Thank you very much.

Comment: Looks like an error to me. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_frame) shows P/Q followed by length/type word.

Comment: @EJP Yes. Guess it is an error in that book. Do you have standard document (e.g, RFC) on this problem? I searched and found none.

Comment: Ethernet is an IEEE standard, you may have to pay for it. Re your second question, your book shows when a length/type word is a length and when a type.

Comment: @EJP The wiki doens't mention other optional tags which were mentioned in the book. So, I really want to know how the BSD stack handles this.

Comment: I doubt that the BSD stack will even see it. More likely the NIC handles all that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an error in the textbook (only in the 2nd edition, see EJP's comment). Not only my code shows the Q-Tag is before the "Length/Type" field. Also see the following open source code from [OpenOnload](http://www.openonload.org/).

*openonload-201405-u1/src/include/ci/net/ethernet.h*

```
typedef struct ci_ether_hdr_s {
  ci_uint8   ether_dhost[ETH_ALEN];
  ci_uint8   ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];
  ci_uint16  ether_type;
} ci_ether_hdr;

typedef struct {
  ci_uint8  ether_dhost[ETH_ALEN];  /* destination eth addr   */
  ci_uint8  ether_shost[ETH_ALEN];  /* source ether addr      */
  ci_uint16 ether_vtype;            /* vlan type field 0x8100 */
  ci_uint16 ether_vtag;             /* vlan tag               */ 
  ci_uint16 ether_type;             /* packet type ID field   */
} ci_ethhdr_vlan_t;
```

Comment: In fairness to the late WRS it should be mentioned that this error does not appear in the first edition which he prepared himself. The second edition was prepared by other hands, some years *post-mortem.*

Comment: @EJP Thanks a lot. I've already added it to my answer. I just had 2nd edition in hand.